# Algorithms for over-segmentation of images

Tags: image-segmentation

I want to over-segment an image as a first step to perform overall image segmentation. Could someone comment on the various algorithms that can be used for over-segmenting images?

Answer (score 1):

The most well known segmentation algorithm that causes over-segmentation is [WATERSHED TRANSFORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_%28image_processing%29) however my question to you is why do you want to do over-segmentation

Can be implemented as follows with MATLAB

```
 L = watershed(A)
L = watershed(A, conn)
```

conn= gives the connected components

Answer (score 1):

The scikit-image python library has over segmentation algorithms that you might find useful. SLIC, Quickshift and Felzenszwalb & Huttenlocher. Examples of their use [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_segmentations.html).